# how to redirect data on same page with data for update in php

Tags: php

I am new in php my query is, how to display data in a text box after an insertion operation. I've a page where I can set the input fields and when I click save button the inputs will be inserted in database and will stay in the same page. This is a product page where a list of products are available and there is an edit and delete button in each row. Now i will click on edit button the data can be edited in the same page.. I'm creating an admin panel.

```
<div class="panel-body">

  <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" action="<?php $_SESSION['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <br/>

    <label>Select Category:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
      <?php
                                            include('config.php');
                                            $query1=mysql_query("select catnm from addcategory");
                                            ?>
        <select class=form-control m-b-10 name=catnm id=catnm>
          <?php
                                             echo"<option>---select---</option required>";
                                            while($query=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
                                            {
                                                 echo "<option value=$query[catnm]>$query[catnm]</option>"; 
                                            }

                                        ?>
        </select>



        <br/>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prodnm" placeholder="Product Name" name="prodnm" required value="<?php 
                             echo $query4['prodnm']; 
                                    ?> " />
          </body>
          <?php
    //coding for insert .

                                                    $catnm=$_POST['catnm'];
                                                    $prodnm=$_POST['prodnm'];
                                                    $prod_dtl=$_POST['prod_dtl'];

                                                    //$updates=$_POST['downld'];
                                                    $date=$_POST['date'];

                                                $query=("insert into addproduct(catnm,prodnm,prod_dtl,pdf,downld,date)
                                                values('$catnm','$prodnm','$prod_dtl','$uploadPath','$updates','$date')");
                                                $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
                                                echo"record inserted";
                                                if($result)
                                                {
                                                    header("location:addProduct.php");
                                                }

    ?>

            <?php

                //coding for update.                            
                                                        include('config.php');
                                                    if(isset($_GET['id']))
                                                    {   
                                                            $id=$_GET['id'];

                                                    echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];      
                                                    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                                                    {

                                                            $updates['downld'] = isset($_POST['downld']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
                                                            $cat['catnm']=$_GET['catnm'];
                                                            $prodnm['prodnm']=$_GET['prodnm'];
    if($query3)
                                                        {
                                                            header('location:addProduct.php');
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                            $query1=mysql_query("select * from addproduct where id='$id'");
                                                            $query4=mysql_fetch_array($query1);

    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your code to make it more readable ?

Comment: And one more thing .. what is it exactly you want to achieve and what have you tried to achieve it ?

Comment: What u want to achieve basically? Pls elaborate...and your coding style is not so good...code contains errors also

Comment: i wants to display data in text box but on single page from i am inserting data . I wants data for update. I thing its done through Query String .. But i need example ..